# Is there a way to distinguish between these function calls coming from two templated base classes?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have the following scenario :-

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
  public:
    virtual void someFunc() {}
};

class Derived : public Base<int>,
                public Base<float> {
  public:
    virtual void someFunc() { 
      // do something different if Base<int> than if Base<float>
    }
};

Derived *d = new D();
Base<int>* b1 = (Base<int>*) d;
Base<float>* b2 = (Base<float>*) d;

b1->someFunc();
b2->someFunc();
```

I want to be able to distinguish between these two function calls. Or in other words, over-ride the two base functions with different function bodies.

Comment: Shouldn't b2 be `Base<float>`?

Comment: What does this mean : `// do something different if Base<int> than if Base<float>`?

Comment: @Nawaz: This appearantly means the OP want's to distinguish if `someFunc()` was called via `Base<int>` or `Base<float>`. Looks like a weird idea to realize s.th. similar as template specialization IMHO.

Comment: @g-makulik Yes that's exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a shim (this works for any instance of name collisions between base classes, whether template-related or not):

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
  public:
    virtual void someFunc() {}
};

class IntShim : public Base<int>
{
  protected:
    virtual void someFuncViaInt() = 0;
  public:
    virtual void someFunc() { return someFuncViaInt(); }
};

class FloatShim : public Base<float>
{
  protected:
    virtual void someFuncViaFloat() = 0;
  public:
    virtual void someFunc() { return someFuncViaFloat(); }
};

class Derived : public IntShim, public FloatShim
{
  protected:
    virtual void someFuncViaInt()
    { 
      // do something for Base<int>
    }
    virtual void someFuncViaFloat()
    { 
      // do something for Base<float>
    }
};

Derived *d = new D();
Base<int>* b1 = (Base<int>*) d;
Base<float>* b2 = (Base<float>*) d;

b1->someFunc();
b2->someFunc();
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could implement this would be to add a dummy parameter to `someFunc` on `Base`:

```
virtual void someFunc(T *dummy = nullptr);
```

In the derived class your overrides are then

```
virtual void someFunc(int *);
virtual void someFunc(float *);
```

Instead of `T *` you could create an empty type

```
template<typename T> struct dispatch {};
...
virtual void someFunc(dispatch<T> = dispatch<T>());
...
virtual void someFunc(dispatch<int>);
virtual void someFunc(dispatch<float>);
```

This removes the (minimal) overhead of passing a nullptr and helps clarify the purpose of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a vitual function and derived class for that. You can just specialize the function from Base class for the known types.

You can do s.th. like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
  public:
    void someFunc()
    {
        // default implementation for any type
    }
};

// specialization for int
template<> void Base<int>::someFunc()
{
}

// specialization for float
template<> void Base<float>::someFunc()
{
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Base<int>* b1 = new Base<int>();
    Base<float>* b2 = new Base<float>();

    b1->someFunc();
    b2->someFunc();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this?  You can't specialize members of a class, you can only specialize the whole class.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Of course, I'm not posting any code that doesn't compile.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Compiler is GCC 4.5.3, I wasn't conscious that s.th. should be wrong with this code?!? But there's no real code inside the specializations, that somehow relates to the template parameter type.

Comment: @BenVoigt : Sure you can -- a non-template member function of a class template is effectively the same as a free-function template, and can be specialized; a member function _template_ of a class template cannot be specialized without also specializing the class template.

Comment: @BenVoigt: (also at @ildjam) I only remember that it's not possible to partially specialze templated member functions owned by a templated class. Is it this what you mean??

Comment: @g-makulik: Partial specialization is probably what I was thinking of.